# Syntax for a cocoapod to get the latest code without :tag

Tags: ios, git, cocoapods

I have a private cocoa pod thats stored in my private repository.

Its setup correctly with:

```
pod 'MyCocoaPod' , :git => 'https://<username>@github.com/account/repo.git', :tag => 'version'
```

And that works all the time.

Except whenever i update the cocoa pod version during development i have to update the version in the project using it.

How do i specify the pod as a declaration so that whenever i run pod update it will get the latest version by itself?

I tried without the tag version and that doesn't work.

Comment: did the answer below work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the available options for this are documented [here](http://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#pod). Based on that documentation you probably want  the same thing you have now without the tag:

```
pod 'MyCocoaPod' , :git => 'https://<username>@github.com/account/repo.git'
```

Since you've said that doesn't work for you instead you can try with a `branch` keyword and just point to `master`:

```
pod 'MyCocoaPod' , :git => 'https://<username>@github.com/account/repo.git', :branch => 'master'
```